# Extend .Net WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net

I'm automating the `WebBrowser` object in order to implement web scraping on pages that work with JavaScript.

It all works fine, but what I want to do now is extend the `WebBrowser` class in order to be able to assign some attributes like `CodSite` and `idScrap`.

How can I do it?

Here is the code:

```
WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.it");

wb1.CodSite = "SITE1";  // property to add to the class
wb1.idScap = 1;         // property to add to the class
```

Thanks to support

Comment: try out decorator pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score -1):

I solved by extending WebBrowser in this way:

```
class WebBrowserJobs: WebBrowser
    {
        public string CodSite { get; set; }
        public int idSkill { get; set; }
        public string CodSkill { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: WebBrowser is a sealed class